# Xcode show UIAlertView after UITableRowSelection?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uialertview

this is my first question, sorry if something is wrong

Well I'm trying to create a view in which i can select a friend from a table view and then it should say the number and the mail on a UIAlertView but I dont know how to do this
the friend list is obtained from an xml file on my site, and then is parsed an showed on a table with a custom cell design

this is the code that creates each cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.messageList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContactListItem"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactListItem" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *userLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    userLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"user"];

    return cell;
}
```

thanks 
Santiago

Comment: Xcode can't in itself show UIAlertViews. You should **not** tag this question as Xcode - in your point it wouldn't make a difference if you used gcc and make directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *name = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"user"];
  NSString *email = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"email"];
  NSString *phone = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"phone"];
  NSString *messageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email : %@\nPhone : %@", email, phone];

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:name message:messageStr delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];   
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath is the method you would need to implement. This is assuming the view you are presenting the table view in is the delegate for the table view.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //Alert view logic happens here getting all the cell information
}
```