# Show AlertView from custom TableViewCell class

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, reactive-cocoa

I have a custom tableViewCell class and viewModel for that cell class. I'm using ReactiveCocoa RACCommand on button. On subscribeNext or error in my custom tableViewCell class implementation, I want to show AlertView with appropriate message. I can not of course show AlertView because method to show AlertView is part of UIView (presentViewController). 
This was my idea:

1. Create protocol for showing alertView

   ```
   @protocol CellDelegate <NSObject>

   -(void) showAlertView:(NSString *) title message:(NSString *) message;

   @end
   ```
2. Store weak reference for this protocol in my custom cell

   ```
   @property (weak) id <CellDelegate> delegate;
   ```
3. Call that delegate when I need to

   ```
   [self.delegate showAlertView:@"Success" message:@"Password changed"];
   ```
4. Implement that protocol in my TableViewController

This method does not work. What to do? How to properly show AlertView from custom tableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand exactly your question but this question cmay be contain what you need.

[Xcode show UIAlertView after UITableRowSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827536/xcode-show-uialertview-after-uitablerowselection)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much, I was an idiot. I forgot to put my delegate to a cell reference.

```
cell.delegate = self
```